# Removing element class onclick using JS (not working)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had a look around but I've not found anything that can really address the issue that I'm having and although I can read and write basic JS I'm still finding it tricky to debug my own problems.

I'm trying to remove a class from an element onclick and for some reason `.removeClass` isn't working as expected. I'm already using some JS to trigger style changes (also onclick) so I know the element ID and classes are correct.

Trigger Element: `#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey`

Class to remove: `.nest-custom-activator`

**Here is part of my working 'style' JS:**

```
<script>
jQuery('#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey').click(function() {
    jQuery('#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey').css({
        'opacity': '0.3',
        'cursor': 'auto',
        'pointer-events': 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is a screenshot and text copy of the trigger element in Console:

**Console Screenshot:**

[image]

**Console Text:**

```
<div class="vc_btn3-container  nest-custom-activator
 wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_fadeIn fadeIn vc_btn3-inline 
 vc_custom_1505915503693 wpb_start_animation animated" id="gsbtns1">
```

**I've tried this JS:**

```
<script>
jQuery('#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey').click(function() {
    jQuery(".vc_btn3-color-grey").removeClass("nest-custom-activator");
});
</script>
```

**and this JS:**

```
<script>
jQuery('#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey').click(function() {
    jQuery("#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey").removeClass("nest-custom-activator");
});
</script>
```

Sadly, neither of these are removing the `.nest-custom-activator` class.

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows it's parent and not the current element. Hence, you need:

```
jQuery('#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("nest-custom-activator");
});
```

Comment: Hey Milan, thank you for this! This is now working! I'll mark as the correct solution when I can :)

Comment: Sure @van. Happy to help! :)

Comment: @MilanChheda Unless I'm mistaken, his will possibly remove the class from multiple other elements. Here's a more explicit solution: `jQuery("#gsbtns1").removeClass("nest-custom-activator");`

Comment: `parent()` only considers the immediate parent and not other elements. Unless, it was `parents()`

Comment: Sure, but `jQuery(".vc_btn3-color-grey")` could target lots of other buttons.

Comment: Yes, in that case, we should and can make minor update to this code.

Comment: @MilanChheda Sorry, it's not my intention to drive you mad or anything, but that will break as soon as `#gsbtns1` is no longer the immediate parent :) Which *could* happen at some point, due to layout changes or whatever.

Comment: @ChrisG - Sure, OP can confirm that, as we aren't aware of the entire HTML. For the given scenario, I believe, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in $(document).ready(function(){})

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey').click(function() {
    $("#gsbtns1 .vc_btn3-color-grey").removeClass("nest-custom-activator");
});

})
</script>
```

And also I guess you element has the id `gsbtns1`  and the class `vc_btn3-color-grey`

```
  $('#gsbtns1.vc_btn3-color-grey')
```

**No space between the Id and the class**

Comment: Hey thanks, I've just tried this and sadly this still isn't removing the class

Comment: copy past your html also

Comment: @Stefdelec While wrapping it in `ready()` is a good idea, it's not the issue here. And your second snippet is also wrong; `.vc_btn3-color-grey` is a child of `#gsbtns1`

Comment: Yes, it is because of the space between the id and the class. It doesn't select what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your jquery code with the below one

html:

```js
$('#gsbtns1.vc_btn3-color-grey').on('click',function() {
    $('#gsbtns1.vc_btn3-color-grey').css({
        'opacity': '0.3',
        'cursor': 'auto',
        'pointer-events': 'none'
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="gsbtns1" class="vc_btn3-container  vc_btn3-color-grey nest-custom-activator  wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_fadeIn fadeIn vc_btn3-inline vc_custom_1505915503693 wpb_start_animation animated" >
test</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt1fxfbp/)